# What are properties of userCtx in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, replication

What are the properties of `userCtx` in `CouchDB` in filter functions (Can be accessed from `req.userCtx`)? Is there any way I can get properties stored at `_users` database for the user from `userCtx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties of [userCtx](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/json-structure.html#user-context-object) object are: `db` for current database name, `name` for current username and `roles` for list of his roles.

This object cannot be extended somehow thought `_users` database and is permanent.